# Game terms dictionary

Tags: javascript, dictionary

I'm pretty new to javascript, but I'm working on a text-based rpg game. I'm trying to figure out how to make it so that if the user types in 'go' or 'walk' or 'run' or 'march' or anything like that, it will run the same command... rather than just doing a bunch of checks using 'or's', I'd prefer to have a dictionary of terms in a separate file that I can check and return a term. How would I go about doing this? Can I use a regular array? if so how do I search it in javascript?

I'd like to get something like

```
dictionary:
    ["go"]:["go"];
    ["walk"]:["go"];
    ["run"]:["go"];
    ["march"]:["go"];
```

I also realize I could be going about this the completely wrong way, so if you have any tips whatsoever they would be very welcome.

Comment: Learn javascript.  You can do an object in javascript which maps values to values. or you could do an associative array but the ideas of dictionary dont exist in javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an object in a separate JS file.

What is a JavaScript object? A JavaScript object is a collection of key/value pairs. I strongly suggest you learn about JavaScript objects, because in JavaScript almost everything is an object.

A simple object looks like this:

```
var myCommads = {
        "go":"go",
        "walk":"go",
        "run":"go",
        "march":"go"
}
```

An object is key-value based. You can access the values via their matching keys.

```
myObject['walk']
```

Will give you the string "go".

Let's say the user inputs a command:

```
var command = prompt("Please give your command", "");
```

Now you check if the command is in your object:

```
if(typeof myCommands[command] == "undefined"){
        alert("Invalid command");
}
else{
      var realCommand = myCommands[command];
      //now do what you want with the command, saved in the variable "realCommand"
}
```

I realize I might be too much information for someone with little JavaScript experience, but to explain all this in detail I would need a lot more time and would need to write a much longer answer.

The best way to completely understand my answer would be to read up on some tutorials:

the prompt function: [JS prompt](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_prompt.asp)

the Alert function: [JS Alert](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_alert.asp)

JavaScript objects: [JS Objects](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_definition.asp)

Answer (score 2):

One way would be something like this:

```
var mydict = [
    {
        words: ['go','walk','run','sprint','move'],
        task: 'move'
    },
    {
        words: ['eat','consume'],
        task: 'eat'
    }
];
```

Then just iterate over it and check if your input command is in any of the objects' `words` array.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for. What would this be called? It looks like an array of something, but I'm not sure what it would be an array of.

Comment: hm.. they are objects, but not sure how you'd call it in terms of your "game engine". Maybe just "entries"

Comment: I think my brain just turned off for the day... thanks for the help though!